# C# WPF login/logout (sessions) - Best practices

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to implement login/logout on my `WPF` app. Because I was asked to keep track if user is logged in or logged out in time.

I was thinking to implement Session table in DB to keep track of each session (`session_start` and `session_end`). That's not problem when user click login and logout. But what if they turn of PC before logout. How I will know when is that worker ended that session (Working time on app).

What is best practice to keep track of session time.

I see problem when I will have sessions without end because PC is turned off (accidentally) and when they turn on PC new session will start from that time and last one will not continue. Maybe store session local to PC and on when I have logout event I will then write in base `session_end`?

Any practices how best to manage this problem?

Comment: You could try to handle the Application.SessionEnding to detect when the user ends the Windows session by logging off: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.sessionending(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This is good for Windows Shooting down, but when restart/shutdown is forced with intention or power loss - Same problem is still there. 
Thanks for this, it's good to know.

Comment: Well, the the application process is shut down anyway. Or are you trying to keep track of the sessions remotely?

Comment: Maybe keep track of the last request time as part of the sever session state and then force logout on the server if a reasonable amount of time has transpired since last request.

Comment: I can't do that because App is used for some sort of ~selling. And when no customers - no requests on app. 

@mm8, We need to keep track is user logged in/logged out on time. When PC is forced to shutdown with reset or power loss, Windows Session event is not called I think. 

Check mine comment on Nick answer down, is maybe that good approach?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a timer that updates the duration of the session in the database every minute.  In this way, if the PC gets turned off, you will have your session time.

(Edited: added clarification that the session info in the db should be updated)

Comment: This is not bad approach. 
What you think about storing local. 
When I get login and write in DBnew session with session_start I write local - UserId, and Session Id. 

And when User turn on PC I check for local and if I have anything I continue that session in app. And wait for proper logout. When logout happens - Delete local and logout user and write in DB session_end?

Comment: I would still recommend updating the database (table Session) on a certain interval, like one minute.  In this way you don't need to care of "log out", because the last update will be basically the end of the session.  You only start new sessions on app launch.  The approach is simple, easy to implement and reliable.